# What's the difference between std::string and std::basic_string? And why are both needed?

Tags: c++, stl

What's the difference between `std::string` and `std::basic_string`? And why are both needed?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`std::basic_string` is a class template for making strings out of character types, `std::string` is a `typedef` for a specialization of that class template for `char`.

Comment: why they are both needed?

Comment: so you are saying that std::string is typedef std::basic_string<char> std::string ?

Comment: @MuhammadAnnaqeeb 2.5 years late but the short answer is to provide wide string (wstring) (Unicode, 2 bytes per character, wchar_t) support as well.

Answer (score 75):

`std::string` is an instantiation of `std::basic_string<T>`:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char> string
```

`std::basic_string` is necessary to have a similar interface for all type of strings (`wstring` for example).

Comment: The proper term is "specialization". `string` is a *specialization* of `basic_string`.

Comment: I guess you could argue about that. "specialization" is usually used to indicate inheritance. A templated {class|function} is instantiated by substituting the template arguments. There is partial template specialization but this isn't used here.

Comment: Referring to a derived class as a 'specialization' is a less formal use of 'specialization'. The word 'specialization' isn't used like this at all in the standard (I'm fairly sure), but its used extensively to describe template specialization. The name of a template specialization can be used in contexts that don't force and implicit instantiation so specialization and instantiation are  separate concepts. As well as a template specialization (the name of a template with a particular set of parameters), there are also partial specializations (class templates only) and explicit specializations.

Comment: Using "specialization" here would be misleading. A template specialization has a specific meaning (unrelated to inheritance), but that's NOT what's used here. std::string is nothing more or less than a typedef, like: `namespace std { typedef basic_string<char> string; }` Technically, it's not really an instantiation either, but it's at least closer (instantiation, by definition, creates an instance, and a typedef only creates a name, not an instance).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: `std::string` is a `typedef` _for_ a specialization of a template. How is the use of "specialization" misleading?

Comment: @Charles: it's misleading because (with templates), "specialization" normally refers to either partial specialization, or explicit specialization, *not* a typedef for what will end up as a simple instantiation.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: I agree that specialization doesn't refer to a typedef, but specialization is used to apply to any template specialization, explicitly specialized or not. This is a very common and correct usage of specialization. I don't see how the usage of "specialization" to refer to `basic_string<char>` is somehow unusual or misleading.

Comment: @Charles, this isn't a specialization though is it? string is a typedef for an instanatiation of the basic_string template with the char type. Whether basic_string is specialized for char is a completely orthogonal matter. On VS2008 basic_string is not specialized for char.

Comment: Isn't it only specialization if you provide "special" code for the template when that type is used?  This is just a typedef that is short hand for instantiating the template with a class of char.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: I think this answer is clearer than the accepted answer in stating that there are the char and wchar_t possibilities to use with the std::basic_string template.

Answer (score 32):

A `std::string` is an instantiation of the `std::basic_string` template with a type of `char`.  You need both so that you can make strings of things besides `char`, such a `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` for a string of wide characters. Or if you want a string with 32 bit elements, `std::basic_string<unsigned int>`.

Comment: I think this should be the top voted answer. It provides a use case of when you wouldn't instantiate `std::basic_string` without a `char` type.

Comment: How do I do cout<< of std::basic_string<unsigned int>. It is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addition to whatever everyone else answered. As `std::string` is a specialization of `basic_string` it also default some other parameters except the char type .A basic_string can have a custom char type (e.g. basic_string can have wide_chars ) , a custom char_trait (e.g. basic_string can have wide chars but support every operation of normal chars) ,and a custom allocator ( a basic_string can have some extra infos packed with it for a custom debugger or a static memory management).

### Usefulness

The `std::string` defaults all this parameters to reasonable values as on most cases you only need an `std::string` and that is it's usefulness. On the other hand whenever you need something more custom you have `std::basic_string`. So both have their different purposes

Answer (score 0):

std::basic_string is a template that lets us create typedefs like std::string as std::basic_string and std::wstring as std::basic_string<wchar_t> so std::string is a specific kind of std::basic_string.

If you're using other kinds of IO std::basic_string can be useful there. For any of the *curses libs you might want to make a typedef for std::basic_string<cchar_t> and whatever structs libcaca and aalib use to draw to the screen.

std::basic_string is useful for a lot of stream or string like parsing. Imagine you're building a scripted dialog system for a game. You want to store strings of the dialogue, but you also need to encode actions like screen shake, or changing the images being displayed, or triggering an animation on some on-screen character. You can use a struct/union to hold each character or the action and have a std::basic_string of that type. If you want to process things differently you could have a std::basic_string of something like this struct.

```cpp
struct Color {
  uint8_t r;
  uint8_t g;
  uint8_t b;
};

struct Word {
  std::string value;
  uint32_t fadeInTimeInMs;
  Color textColor;
  uint8_t fontId;
  uint8_t textSize;
};
```

Then your source text could look something like this.

```
In our {color:{100,100,100}family,} there {textSize:{8},fadeInTimeInMs:{750}was {textSize:{10},textColor:{150,0,30}no} clear} line between religion and fly fishing.
```

You could parse that into a std_basic_string and then when you're rendering to the screen you can use the per word styles.