# Having hard time understanding std::basic_string memory allocation

Tags: c++, stl, stdstring

I'm currently learning STL and I came across an example made by one of my teachers.

```
template <class T>
struct SpyAllocator : std::allocator<T>
{
typedef T   value_type;

SpyAllocator(/*vector args*/) = default;

template<class U>
SpyAllocator(const SpyAllocator<U>& other){}

template<class U>
struct rebind
{
    using other = SpyAllocator<U>;
};

T*  allocate(std::size_t n)
{
    T* p = (T*) new char[sizeof(T) * n];

    memorySpy.NotifyAlloc(sizeof(T), n, p);
    return p;
};

void    deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
{
    memorySpy.NotifyDealloc(p, n);
    delete (char*)p;
}

typedef T*          pointer;
typedef const T*    const_pointer;
typedef T&          reference;
typedef const T&    const_reference;
};

template <class T, class U>
bool    operator==(const SpyAllocator<T>&, const SpyAllocator<U>&) { return 
false; }

template <class T, class U>
bool    operator!=(const SpyAllocator<T>&, const SpyAllocator<U>&) { return 
false; }
```

Above is his allocator implementation.

```
#define String      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, SpyAllocator<char>>
```

He defined `std::basic_string` as `String`.

In the main.cpp file,

```
int main()
{
    DO(String s1 = "Bonjour");
    DO(String s2 = " le monde !");
    DO(String s3 = s1 + s2);
    printf("s3 : %s\n", s3.c_str());

    printf("\nDestroy vector\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

He is testing + operator and copy constructor and the result is

```
String s1 = "Bonjour"

String s2 = " le monde !"

String s3 = s1 + s2
*** Allocate block 1 : 31 elem of 1 bytes

s3 : Bonjour le monde !

Destroy vector

*** Deallocate block 1 : 31 elem of 1 bytes
```

my questions are:

1- I've counted the number of characters(including \0) of `String s1` and `String s2`, it's 19. But 31 is allocated. `Allocate block 1 : 31 elem of 1 bytes`

What is the reason behind this?

2- It seems like `String s1` and `String s2` constructors did not allocate any memory but `String s1` and `String s2` still have the value.

How is it possible?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `#define String ...` **really bad idea**. Don't use the preprocessor for this, use a type alias: `using String = ...` (just changing exactly the `#define String` into `using String = ` will do everything you need)

Comment: @Justin, thank you for the comment, I'll remember it. But it's made by one of my teachers.

Comment: _"...did not allocate any memory ..."_  lookup: "small string optimisation" (small strings are allocation in the std::string class directly not on the heap via the allocator).  Also strings (and vector) sometimes can grow by a multiple of the space required. (1.6 and 2 are common multiples)

Comment: I think your teacher has made a mistake, because he's pairing `new[]` with `delete`, which is UB.

Comment: Thank you @Richard Critten! I've been on this subject since yesterday and couldn't figure out the reason behind it. You just saved my day!

Comment: @ChristianHackl, it's been 2 weeks and half with C++ and I didn't get what you want to point out. So new with delete = ok but new[] with delete = not ok? So it should be new[] with delete [] ?

Comment: @HanseulSHIN: Wow, if it's been 2 weeks and a half with C++, then you should not struggle with an exotic voodoo feature like custom allocators! What does your teacher think this will accomplish?! In any case, yes, you must pair `new` with `delete` and `new[]` with `delete[]`, or else the behaviour of your program is undefined. And `new[]`/`delete[]` is almost always a bad idea anyway; you will notice that the standard library instead uses placement new to separate memory management from constructor/destructor calls. However, as I said, this is *far* from beginner's stuff.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thank you for your answer! I'll remember that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what we get when we look at the **basic_string.h** of the **STDLib**

```
enum
{
    _S_local_capacity = 15 / sizeof(_CharT)
};

union
{
    _CharT _M_local_buf[_S_local_capacity + 1];
    size_type _M_allocated_capacity;
};
```

[We know that `std::string` is a `typedef` for a specialization of a std::basic_string with `char` type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662107/whats-the-difference-between-stdstring-and-stdbasic-string-and-why-are-bot)

[`basic_string` contains a 15 bytes fixed buffer for short strings then we +1 for the `\0`.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a59970d-c7bf-4ed5-8267-e482c4e461a7/stl-string-is-a-memory-hog?forum=vclanguage) So when we concatenate 2 strings which are stored into the small buffer, it will concatenate the whole then add +1 for the `\0`. So it will be 15 + 15 + 1 = 31.

That's what I understood from the reading of `basic_string.h`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!