# What are some good scenarios to use a cstring over a string?

Tags: c++

I've made quite a few projects (small) now with C++ and was wondering, what would be some good scenarios in which it is better to use a cstring instead of a string?

Just to clarify, I'm not calling cstrings bad. I'm just genuinely interested if they are as important as regular strings in C++

Comment: What do you mean by "cstring"? null-terminated `char` arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between string and char\[\] types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287306/difference-between-string-and-char-types-in-c) or [Difference between string and char\[\] types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287306/difference-between-string-and-char-types-in-c) or [What's the difference between std::string and std::basic_string? And why are both needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662107/whats-the-difference-between-stdstring-and-stdbasic-string-and-why-are-bot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` allocates dynamic memory at runtime for its character data (unless the `std::string` implementation employs "Short String Optimization" and the data is short enough to fit in the SSO buffer).

So, one scenario you may want to use C-style strings for is when you want to pass around string literals without allocating memory for them.  Assigning a string literal to a `std::string` will allocate dynamic memory (if SSO is not used).

There can also be scenarios where you want to *process* character data without allocating new memory for extracted substrings.  C-style strings can be good for that, too (though `std::string_view` in C++17 and later would generally be better for that).

Answer (score -1):

cstrings are just character arrays will a null character to terminate them. While std::string are dynamically allocated. Able to have more memory control; basically memory management is the main advantage

Comment: You may want to rethink this answer. The questioner is looking for cases where a cstring, presumably a null terminated character array is preferable to a string, presumably a  `std::string`, not looking for the differences between the two or the advantages of `string` over `char` array.